# SQL Firebird conditional where not using index

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.1

I am using Firebird SQL version 2.1.

I have a sql query string in which parameters are passed. 
If a value is passed is not in my hand, but if it is passed, it is the right type (Timestamp or else..)

Now my query looks like this:

```
select r.* 
from TableA 
where r.ACTION_DATE >= iif('2019-10-09 00:00:00' is null or '2019-10-09 00:00:00' = '', r.ACTION_DATE, '2019-10-09 00:00:00')
```

In words, when a value is passed I want to load all records that have an action date greater then '2019-10-09 00:00:00', else get all records.

I have an Index on column ACTION_DATE. For the query I mentioned the index is not applied!

For the same query without the condition the index is applied:

```
select r.* 
from TableA 
where r.ACTION_DATE >= '2019-10-09 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Having a condition like `'2019-10-09 00:00:00' is null or '2019-10-09 00:00:00' = ''` doesn't make much sense to me. It sounds like that whatever generates this query can already determine that condition and then choose either not to execute (as `r.ACTION_DATE > r.ACTION_DATE` is false), or use `r.ACTION_DATE > '2019-10-09 00:00:00'`

Comment: Sorry, my fault I updated the query it should be '>='

Comment: That would be the same as just using `select r.* from TableA` in the first case.

Comment: Yes, at the end it is a conditional parameterisation, so if you want to filter you can pass a value ..

Comment: Have you tried `(your condition) or not(your condition) and r.ACTION_DATE > '2019-10-09 00:00:00'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressions on columns generally kill the use of indexes.  Some databases can handle an explicit `OR`:

```
select r.* 
from TableA 
where r.ACTION_DATE >= '2019-10-09 00:00:00' OR
      '2019-10-09 00:00:00' IS NULL;
```

Otherwise, `UNION ALL` can handle it:

```
select r.* 
from TableA r
where r.ACTION_DATE >= '2019-10-09 00:00:00' 
union all
select r.*
from TableA r
where '2019-10-09 00:00:00' IS NULL;
```

Note that the first subquery returns no rows if the value is `NULL` so there is no danger of duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't worked with Interbase/Firebird in decades, but  but my guess would be that the right side is not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

The DBMS has to get the row *first*, to get the value of `r.ACTION_DATE`, to evaluate the expression on the right side, and only then can it determine whether to keep the row in the result, at which point it's too late to use the index (we have already retrieved the row so there is no need to seek for it through the index).

Try pre-evaluating the expression and then using the resulting value in your WHERE clause (with parameter binding and all that, of course).

---

Another thing to watch out for is that an index is helpful only if the selectivity is good enough. If you retrieve too many rows (as a rule of thumb: more than 10% of the entire table), then it's generally faster to just linearly traverse the entire table even if an index is usable.

Comment: The only thing I could do is to use execute blocks and to pre evaluate the parameter, but I wanted to avoid this..